# How restrictive is it for a symplectic form to represent an integral cohomology class?

Tags: differential-topology, symplectic-geometry

In Donaldson's papers on symplectic hypersurfaces and Lefschetz pencils for symplectic manifolds, he considers symplectic manifolds $(M, \omega)$ where the cohomology class $[\omega/2\pi] \in H^2(M; \mathbb{R})$ lies in the integral lattice $H^2(M; \mathbb{Z})$.

How restrictive of a condition is this on the symplectic manifold? In particular, I'd be interested in knowing if there is or is not a smooth manifold which admits *no* symplectic forms representing an integral cohomology class in this way.

Comment: Do you assume that $M$ is compact? (This is Donaldson's setting.) What are your thoughts about the question? For instance, do you know that a small perturbation of a symplectic form (to a closed form) is still symplectic (assuming $M$ is compact)?

Comment: Yes, we are assuming $M$ is compact. In this case, we can slightly $C^0$ perturb $\omega$ to a non-degenerate two-form so that its integrals on $H_2(M; \mathbb{Z})$ are in $2\pi\mathbb{Q}$ (since the rationals are dense), and then scale it up to get an integral two-form. However, I don't think it's clear that we can keep this two-form closed. We can keep it closed by realizing our perturbation as a small isotopy of $M$, but in this case it is unclear if we can construct such an isotopy to specifically make the integrals rational.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $M$ is compact. Let $\omega_1,...,\omega_k\in \Omega^2(M)$ be closed forms which project to a basis of $H^2_{dR}(M)$. Let $\omega$ be a symplectic form on $M$. Then for $a_1,...,a_k\in {\mathbb R}$ sufficiently close to $0$, the linear combination
$$
\eta= \omega+ \sum_{i=1}^k a_i \omega_i
$$
is nondegenerate; it is of course, closed no matter what $a_i$'s are. Hence, the form $\eta$ is symplectic (if all $a_i$'s are close to zero). The projection of the set of such forms to $H^2_{dR}(M)$ forms a neighborhood of $[\omega]$ since $[\omega_1],...,[\omega_k]$ was a basis of $H^2_{dR}(M)$. Thus, for a dense subset of parameters $a_i$, the cohomology class of $\eta$ is rational. Hence, after rescaling,  it is integral. Thus, every compact symplectic manifold admits an integral symplectic form. I am not sure about noncompact case, but you do not care about it anyhow.

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to add something I also learned from a friend for the sake of any readers. By this construction, any symplectic form can be deformed very slightly to a rational multiple of an integral one. Since being a symplectic submanifold is an "open" condition and invariant under scaling by constants, this implies the Donaldson construction yields a symplectic hypersurface for any symplectic form.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I'm studying a case in which $M$ is not necessarily compact, do you know of any paper or book that treats perturbation of symplectic forms (closed forms) in this setting?

Comment: @AaronMaroja: Sorry, I do not know any references for that. The first question you have to ask yourself is: Do you want to perturb $\omega$ using elements of $H_c^2(M, {\mathbb R})$? Do you want to assume that $H_c^2(M, {\mathbb R})$ is finite-dimensional? In the case of "yes" on both, the construction I described still works. Otherwise, you have to introduce some analytic conditions to ensure convergence and nondegeneracy of the perturbed 2-form. (For working on open manifolds, $L^2$-conditions tend to be useful.)