# A Question about 3-manifold with a Non-vanishing harmonic 1-form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $Y$ be a closed oriented 3-manifold with Riemannian metric and suppose there exists a 1-form $v$ such that $dv=0$, $d\star v=0$ and |v|>0 in every point.

What will be the topology of this 3-manifold? Can we conclude that this 3-manifold is $S^1\times \Sigma$ with $\Sigma$ a Riemann surface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M$ is fibered over $S^1$, you get a closed nonvanishing 1-form by taking pull-back of the angle form $d\theta$ from $S^1$. As for making this form harmonic, yes: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75038/when-is-a-closed-differential-form-harmonic-relative-to-some-metric/75136.

Conversely, if $M$ admits a closed nonvanishing 1-form $\omega$ then $M$ fibers over $S^1$: This is a corollary of Tishler's theorem. Tishler's theorem requires $\omega$ to have integer periods but this is easy to arrange (the same argument as in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3225748/how-restrictive-is-it-for-a-symplectic-form-to-represent-an-integral-cohomology/3227076#3227076)).

Comment: This is an amazing answer, thanks a lot.